# Is it possible to reply to a twitter mention with TwitterAPIExchange php

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I have been testing this script and was able to get it to work to replying to tweets that I post on my own timeline, but I am trying to get it to work with Twitter mentions. All the data is passing correctly like the `in_reply_to_status_id` that I get from that mention, but it seems to not work.

The only other POST that I can see that "might" be what I need is `POST direct_messages/events/new (message_create)` but I don't want to send a private message, I want to reply to that mention.

I am suspecting that I cannot reply to a mention like I could to my own tweets.

**Is there a way to reply to a mention and how do I do it or what am I doing wrong?**

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => $twitter_accesstoken,
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => $twitter_accesstokensecret,
    'consumer_key' => $twitter_apikey,
    'consumer_secret' => $twitter_apisecret
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
$postfields = array(
    'in_reply_to_status_id' => $in_reply_to_status_id, 
    'status' => $status
);

$requestMethod = 'POST';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setPostfields($postfields)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
```

}

**Solved**

I figured it out. My code was fine I just needed to add `"@username " . $status` to status and it worked.

Also something else I learned that I think is worth mentioning to help others is it is important to look at the response at the `in_reply_to_status_id_str` field when returned. If it is blank then it is a new tweet, if it is not blank like `123456789123456789` That ID is the ID of the original tweet so you can relate the difference between the tweet and the reply to that tweet.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Im going to edit my question, but could you explain how?